# Comparing tensors in TensorFlow

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I have two TensorFlow tensors each being outputed from object detector network, each containing this shape (batch, height, width, detected_boxes * num_classes). I want to compare each box from each tensor with the other using a siamese sub network.
I want the network to be end-to-end, so what is the correct approach, should I use TensorFlow while loop, and do some sort of nested loop?